# A slow query in Oracle (runs fast in SQL Server) (a correlated subquery)

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

We are annoyed by the symptom below. We would appreciate any advice from you about the cause of it and the way to resolve it.

I run the simple query below and it took 3,800 seconds for Oracle DB to return the result, while the same query completes in a few seconds in a SQL Server database that has the same tables. (It's used as a datamart).

**Query:**

```
select
T_X.Col1
,(select count(1) from T_X where T_X.colX = T_Y.colY) as cnt1
from T_Y
```

**Records count:**

T_X:  96,536

T_Y: 129,359

**Other info:**

-ColY is the primary key of T_Y and there is no index on ColXin in both of the two enrironment.

-Oracle 11.1 (ran the query using SQL Developer)

-SQL Server 2008 (ran the query using SSMS)

-No big differences of hardware specs between the two environment.

-The query above is a part of the bigger one. We simplified it and find the part was the bottleneck.

We would appreciate your advice!

**Additional Info (the purpose of the query)**

The query above is a part of the query below. Our purpose is to find out (the count of) records in T_Y that doesn't have correspondent records in other tables (T_A, T_B, T_C, T_D, T_E, T_X).

```
select          
  count(1)          
from            
  (select
     T_Y.ColA
    ,T_Y.ColG
    ,T_Y.ColH
    ,(select count(1) from T_A A where A.ColA = T_Y.ColY) as cnt1
    ,(select count(1) from T_B B where B.ColB = T_Y.ColY) as cnt2
    ,(select count(1) from T_X where T_X.ColX = T_Y.ColY) as cnt3
    ,(select count(1) from T_C C where C.ColC = T_Y.ColY) as cnt4
    ,(select count(1) from T_D D where D.ColD = T_Y.ColY) as cnt5
    ,(select count(1) from T_E E where E.ColE = T_Y.ColY) as cnt6
  from T_Y
  )XXX
where 1=1
  and XXX.ColH in ('X')
  and XXX.cnt1 = 0
  and XXX.cnt2 = 0
  and XXX.cnt3 = 0
  and XXX.cnt4 = 0
  and XXX.cnt5 = 0
  and XXX.cnt6 = 0
;
```

**Execution Plan** - Oracle (for the original query)(Execute Explain Plan)

```
"Optimizer" "Cost"  "Cardinality"   "Bytes" "Partition Start"   "Partition Stop"    "Partition Id"  "ACCESS PREDICATES" "FILTER PREDICATES"
"SELECT STATEMENT"  "ALL_ROWS"  "121"   "129359"    "776154"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"SORT(AGGREGATE)"   ""  ""  "1" "6" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"TABLE ACCESS(FULL) XXXXX.T_X"  "ANALYZED"  "6616"  "2" "12"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""T_X"."ColX"=:B1"
"INDEX(FAST FULL SCAN) XXXXX.T_Y_0" "ANALYZED"  "121"   "129359"    "776154"    ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
```

**Execution Plan** - SQL Server (for the original query)

Line 7 indicates that SQL server uses Clustered Index Scan instead of Table Scan though the clustered index doesn't include ColumnY. Could anyone explain what does this mean? **Can I force Oracle to use the similar Execution Plan using hint clause or anything?**

```
  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1008]=CASE WHEN [Expr1006] IS NULL THEN (0) ELSE [Expr1006] END))
       |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
            |--Hash Match(Right Outer Join, HASH:([DB_X].[dbo].[T_X].[ColX])=([DB_X].[dbo].[T_Y].[ColY]), RESIDUAL:([DB_X].[dbo].[T_X].[ColX]=[DB_X].[dbo].[T_Y].[ColY]))
                 |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1006]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(int,[Expr1013],0)))
                 |    |--Hash Match(Aggregate, HASH:([DB_X].[dbo].[T_X].[ColX]), RESIDUAL:([DB_X].[dbo].[T_X].[ColX] = [DB_X].[dbo].[T_X].[ColX]) DEFINE:([Expr1013]=COUNT(*)))
                 |         |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([DB_X].[dbo].[T_X].[ColX]))
                 |              |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([DB_X].[dbo].[T_X].[PK_T_X]))
                 |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([DB_X].[dbo].[T_Y].[ColY]))
                      |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([DB_X].[dbo].[T_Y].[PK_T_Y]))
```

Comment: your query is confusing. describe in words what your intention is -- that helps sometimes.

Comment: Correction: colY is the primary key of T_Y.

Comment: Please post the execution plans for the queries in both databases.

Comment: matias elgart, Thanks for the advice! I added the "additional info"

Comment: sstan, Thanks for the advice! I added the execution plans. I'm not familiar with the oracle and please let me know if there are better ways to get the execution plan in text format.

Comment: count(1) is no faster than count(*) -- in Oracle, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Our purpose is to find out (the count of) records in T_Y that doesn't have correspondent records in other tables (T_A, T_B, T_C, T_D, T_E, T_X).

That would better be expressed as:

```
select          
  count(*)          
from            
  T_Y
where ColH in ('X') and
      not exists (select null from T_A A where A.ColA = T_Y.ColY) and
      not exists (select null from T_B B where B.ColB = T_Y.ColY) and
      not exists (select null from T_X where T_X.ColX = T_Y.ColY) and
      not exists (select null from T_C C where C.ColC = T_Y.ColY) and
      not exists (select null from T_D D where D.ColD = T_Y.ColY) and
      not exists (select null from T_E E where E.ColE = T_Y.ColY);
```

Comment: David, thanks so much for the resolution! Your SQL retrieved the results in just 2 minutes (with cleared cache).

Answer (score 0):

You need an index on `t_x(colX)`.  I am guessing this index exists on SQL Server.

This version might be faster on either machine:

```
select t_x.colX, count(1)
from T_X 
group by t_x.colX;
```

It is not exactly the same, but it might be what you really want.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! As I corrected the original post, colY was the primary key of T_Y. However, the two environments share the same conditions about the keys and the indexes.

Comment: I think adding an index will work fine, but we are not allowed to make any change to the definitions of the objects as the DB is a part of the package software. I thought if it worked fine in SQL Server without any change to the definitions, why not in Oracle.

Comment: This might be a case where SQL Server optimizes the query better than Oracle, although that would surprise me.  Oracle is usually pretty good with this type of query.

Comment: Gordon, thanks for the comment! It's difficult for me to understand this part: Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([DB_X].[dbo].[T_X].[PK_T_X])). SQL server uses Clustered Index Scan instead of Table Scan though the clustered index doesn't include ColumnY.

Comment: @yobioo in [tag:sql-server] the clustered index includes every column.

Comment: mendosi, thanks for pointing it out! Probably, I should have written ColumnY is not used for sorting records in the clustered indexes.